# How to Print listof projects

Tags: java, jira

i would like to retrive all the projects from the jira.
So i used these lines

```
ProjectManager pm = cm.getProjectManager();
pm.getProjects();
```

It runs nice. but i want to see the list of projects...

How to do that?

Please Guide me soon with few examples..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "see the list of projects". But if you just want to print them out:

```
List<ProjectObject> list = pm.getProjectObjects();
for(Project po : list){
    System.out.println(po.getKey() + " " + po.getName() + " " + getDescription()); 
}
```